# git: remove file in master branch only - for all times

Tags: git, merge

I have a file in the repo which is used for development and test only. In production, we don't need that file.

Now, it's easy to remove it from the `master` branch only.

But what about future merges from the `test` branch?

Our development process is a standard `dev-test-prod`, and code pushed to `test` will be just merged onto `master` for production.

If in the `test` branch that file is present, how can it be prevented from being merged again onto `master`?

Comment: It shouldn't re-add the file when you merge from the `test` branch.  If you remove it from `master` and edit it in `test` then you'll get a merge conflict.

Comment: It seems to me that instead of trying to force your git workflow, you might want to change your release one, because it doesn't sound absurd to me to have a test file in a repo, even on master. Perhaps https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/excluding-files-from-git-archive/ could be your solution.

Comment: @dan, you are right! If I don't change the file at all (which will be our case), the file won't be merged! You may provide your comment as a solution so I can accept it. But I am puzzled - why doesn't it re-add? Doesn't a merge mean "put the differences of test onto master"?

Comment: It's closer to "put the changes made on test onto master", so if the file you deleted wasn't changed on test then it keeps whatever state it's in on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file won't be re-added when you merge the `test` branch into `master`.

If you remove it from `master` and edit it in `test` you will get a merge conflict, but if you don't edit it in `test` it will keep whatever state it has on `master`.